# excel if and if error formula that has used 140 times and it throws an errors saying we can use it only 64 times

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, find

I have 140 unique numbers and trying to find that through the list which can be used in vba

The formula works fine till 64 ifs are used, later I am having a trouble

=IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IF(FIND("5216",A2,1)>0,"00000A-5216",""),IF(FIND("5140",A2,1)>0,"00000B-5140","")),IF(FIND("5148",A2,1)>0,"00000C-5148","")),IF(FIND("5117",A2,1)>0,"00000D-5117","")),IF(FIND("5204",A2,1)>0,"00000E-5204","")),IF(FIND("5238",A2,1)>0,"00000F-5238","")),IF(FIND("5203",A2,1)>0,"00000G-5203","")),IF(FIND("5237",A2,1)>0,"00000H-5237","")),IF(FIND("5051",A2,1)>0,"5051","")),IF(FIND("0101",A2,1)>0,"0101","")),IF(FIND("0700",A2,1)>0,"0700","")),IF(FIND("3208",A2,1)>0,"3208","")),IF(FIND("3209",A2,1)>0,"3209","")),IF(FIND("3900",A2,1)>0,"3900","")),IF(FIND("3901",A2,1)>0,"3901","")),IF(FIND("5029",A2,1)>0,"5029","")),IF(FIND("5030",A2,1)>0,"5030","")),IF(FIND("5032",A2,1)>0,"5032","")),IF(FIND("5033",A2,1)>0,"5033","")),IF(FIND("5036",A2,1)>0,"5036","")),IF(FIND("5049",A2,1)>0,"5049","")),IF(FIND("5067",A2,1)>0,"5067","")),IF(FIND("5068",A2,1)>0,"5068","")),IF(FIND("5069",A2,1)>0,"5069","")),IF(FIND("5072",A2,1)>0,"5072","")),IF(FIND("5073",A2,1)>0,"5073","")),IF(FIND("5075",A2,1)>0,"5075","")),IF(FIND("5076",A2,1)>0,"5076","")),IF(FIND("5078",A2,1)>0,"5078","")),
IF(FIND("5079",A2,1)>0,"5079","")),IF(FIND("5080",A2,1)>0,"5080","")),IF(FIND("5081",A2,1)>0,"5081","")),IF(FIND("5082",A2,1)>0,"5082","")),IF(FIND("5083",A2,1)>0,"5083","")),IF(FIND("5090",A2,1)>0,"5090","")),IF(FIND("5094",A2,1)>0,"5094","")),IF(FIND("5095",A2,1)>0,"5095","")),IF(FIND("5100",A2,1)>0,"5100","")),IF(FIND("5106",A2,1)>0,"5106","")),IF(FIND("5124",A2,1)>0,"5124","")),IF(FIND("5125",A2,1)>0,"5125","")),IF(FIND("5126",A2,1)>0,"5126","")),IF(FIND("5147",A2,1)>0,"5147","")),IF(FIND("5150",A2,1)>0,"5150","")),IF(FIND("5151",A2,1)>0,"5151","")),IF(FIND("5155",A2,1)>0,"5155","")),IF(FIND("5156",A2,1)>0,"5156","")),IF(FIND("5157",A2,1)>0,"5157","")),IF(FIND("5158",A2,1)>0,"5158","")),IF(FIND("5159",A2,1)>0,"5159","")),IF(FIND("5194",A2,1)>0,"5194","")),IF(FIND("5195",A2,1)>0,"5195","")),IF(FIND("5196",A2,1)>0,"5196","")),IF(FIND("5205",A2,1)>0,"5205","")),IF(FIND("5227",A2,1)>0,"5227","")),IF(FIND("5228",A2,1)>0,"5228",""))IF(FIND("5229",A2,1)>0,"5229","")),IF(FIND("5234",A2,1)>0,"5234","")),IF(FIND("5241",A2,1)>0,"5241","")),IF(FIND("5242",A2,1)>0,"5242","")),IF(FIND("5243",A2,1)>0,"5243","")),IF(FIND("5244",A2,1)>0,"5244","")),IF(FIND("5254",A2,1)>0,"5254","")),IF(FIND("5255",A2,1)>0,"5255","")),IF(FIND("5267",A2,1)>0,"5267","")),IF(FIND("5269",A2,1)>0,"5269","")),IF(FIND("5271",A2,1)>0,"5271","")),IF(FIND("5278",A2,1)>0,"5278","")),IF(FIND("5280",A2,1)>0,"5280","")),IF(FIND("5286",A2,1)>0,"5286","")),IF(FIND("5297",A2,1)>0,"5297","")),IF(FIND("5305",A2,1)>0,"5305","")),IF(FIND("5306",A2,1)>0,"5306","")),IF(FIND("5310",A2,1)>0,"5310","")),IF(FIND("5315",A2,1)>0,"5315","")),IF(FIND("5316",A2,1)>0,"5316","")),IF(FIND("5318",A2,1)>0,"5318","")),IF(FIND("5321",A2,1)>0,"5321","")),IF(FIND("5322",A2,1)>0,"5322","")),IF(FIND("5324",A2,1)>0,"5324","")),IF(FIND("5325",A2,1)>0,"5325","")),IF(FIND("5326",A2,1)>0,"5326","")),IF(FIND("5327",A2,1)>0,"5327","")),IF(FIND("5328",A2,1)>0,"5328","")),IF(FIND("5336",A2,1)>0,"5336","")),IF(FIND("5337",A2,1)>0,"5337","")),IF(FIND("5339",A2,1)>0,"5339","")),IF(FIND("5341",A2,1)>0,"5341","")),IF(FIND("5350",A2,1)>0,"5350",""))IF(FIND("5351",A2,1)>0,"5351","")),IF(FIND("5352",A2,1)>0,"5352","")),IF(FIND("5353",A2,1)>0,"5353","")),IF(FIND("5356",A2,1)>0,"5356","")),IF(FIND("5357",A2,1)>0,"5357","")),IF(FIND("5358",A2,1)>0,"5358","")),IF(FIND("5359",A2,1)>0,"5359","")),IF(FIND("5360",A2,1)>0,"5360","")),IF(FIND("5361",A2,1)>0,"5361","")),IF(FIND("5362",A2,1)>0,"5362","")),IF(FIND("5363",A2,1)>0,"5363","")),IF(FIND("5378",A2,1)>0,"5378","")),IF(FIND("5379",A2,1)>0,"5379","")),IF(FIND("5380",A2,1)>0,"5380","")),IF(FIND("5381",A2,1)>0,"5381","")),IF(FIND("5382",A2,1)>0,"5382","")),IF(FIND("5383",A2,1)>0,"5383","")),IF(FIND("5389",A2,1)>0,"5389",""))IF(FIND("5390",A2,1)>0,"5390","")),IF(FIND("5392",A2,1)>0,"5392","")),IF(FIND("6000",A2,1)>0,"6000","")),IF(FIND("6001",A2,1)>0,"6002","""")),IF(FIND("6003",A2,1)>0,"6003","")),IF(FIND("6004",A2,1)>0,"6004","")),IF(FIND("6005",A2,1)>0,"6005","")),IF(FIND("6006",A2,1)>0,"6006","")),IF(FIND("6653",A2,1)>0,"6653","")),IF(FIND("6654",A2,1)>0,"6654","")),IF(FIND("6655",A2,1)>0,"6655","")),IF(FIND("6656",A2,1)>0,"6656","")),IF(FIND("6657",A2,1)>0,"6657","")),IF(FIND("9202",A2,1)>0,"9202","")),IF(FIND("9401",A2,1)>0,"9401","")),RIGHT(A2,3,4))"

the result should return the number mentioned and I am planning to sort them in ascending order.

The value in `A2` looks like `PMGAG5216GC`, `PMG005216GC`, `PMGVV5140GC`, `PMG005140GC`, `PMGVV5148GCW`, `PMGAG5117GCW`, `PMG005117GCW`, `PMGAG5204GCB`, `PMG005204GCB`, `PMGAG5238GCB`, `PMGVV5238GCB`, `PMG005238GCB`, `PMGAG5203GCB`, etc. these are some sample order numbers that are being updated and the numbers `5238` is a number that I have to find from that order to sort them in ascending order. In the same way, I have 140 numbers that have to found to sort them accordingly. The 4 digit numbers are fixed in the orders and it should be one from the 140 number list that I had mentioned

Comment: Whatever is wrong with this, it looks like the wrong way to do whatever it is you're doing.

Comment: At least "5350",""))IF(FIND("5351", and "5389",""))IF(FIND("5390" seem to have the , missing !? And there must be a better way to do this, please explain your problem more in words, like where do the values to compare to come from, can you use the fact most follow each other (like 6000-6006) and so on

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57101721/edit) to let us know what you are trying to accomplish? Some sample data and expected outcome would also be useful

Comment: Also note that there's a hard limit on the number of characters that will be accepted in a single cell.

Comment: What does the content of cell `A2` look like?

Comment: In versions of Excel after 2007, the limit for nested `IF` statements was increased from 7 to 64. You've hit the 64-deep limit, so you're done. That said, please give us more info so we can help you find a _much_ better way of doing this (as this method is... awkward... at best).

Comment: PMGAG5216GC
PMG005216GC
PMGVV5140GC
PMG005140GC
PMGVV5148GCW
PMGAG5117GCW
PMG005117GCW
PMGAG5204GCB
PMG005204GCB
PMGAG5238GCB
PMGVV5238GCB
PMG005238GCB
PMGAG5203GCB these are some sample order numbers that are being updated and the numbers 5238 is a number that I have to find from that order to sort them in ascending order. In the same way, I have 140 numbers that have to found to sort them accordingly.  The 4 digit numbers are fixed in the orders and it should be one from the 140 number list that I had mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb, if you see yourself nesting anything deeper than 5 or 6 levels, stop and take the time to see if there wouldn't be a more easily maintainable way to do the same thing. Hitting hard limits (e.g. 64 levels of nesting) is rarely a sign that things are done in an optimal fashion.

> PMGAG5216GC PMG005216GC PMGVV5140GC PMG005140GC PMGVV5148GCW PMGAG5117GCW PMG005117GCW PMGAG5204GCB PMG005204GCB PMGAG5238GCB PMGVV5238GCB PMG005238GCB PMGAG5203GCB

Assuming the format is consistently the same, you can grab the 4 characters starting at the 6th position, and then verify if these 4 characters exist in a lookup table that contains the 140 values you're interested in. The `MID` function can be used to do this.

You could leverage the fact that VLOOKUP in the first column of the lookup table would return the lookup value itself, and a lookup failure would be `#N/A`, so wrapping it with `IFERROR` to turn that into an empty string would look like this:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(MID(A2,6,4),theLookupTable[TheLookupColumn],1,FALSE),"")
```

Now, if looks like some of the values need a prefix e.g. "00000A-"; include that prefix (with the dash, so you don't have to conditionally add it in the formula) in the lookup table (say, in some `[Prefix]` column) where it's needed, and just concatenate it after the lookup.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(MID(A2,6,4),theLookupTable[TheLookupColumn],1,FALSE) & VLOOKUP(MID(A2,6,4),theLookupTable[@[TheLookupColumn]:[ThePrefixColumn]],2,FALSE),"")
```

Better if you can turn the `MID(A2,6,4)` part into a helper cell instead of computing it twice - use that `MID` function on your source data to populate the lookup table.

The lookup table might look like this:

```
TheLookupColumn  ThePrefixColumn
5216             00000A-
5140             00000B-
5148             00000C-
...
3901             
...
```

Sort the table by `TheLookupColumn`, and the lookups should be pretty fast.

Comment: THanks for update, but the format is consistently not the same. PMGGN0H3208DVCC This is another type of order where we cannot use the mid function

Comment: @KalyanKumar in that case consider writing a simple UDF that works with a simple [regular expression pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22542835/1188513) (the pattern would look like `\d{4}` to match 4 consecutive digit characters. The function would return the matched string, and you substitute the `MID` form this answer with that custom regex-powered UDF. The crux of the answer remains the same - use a lookup table.

Comment: I am not familiar with UDF, how does that work exactly?

Comment: You just make a `Public Function` in a standard VBA module, and call it from a cells, e.g. `=MyFunction(A2)`

Comment: @KalyanKumar Note that "lookup _table_" actually means using Excels "Table" formatting. Select the cell that contains `TheLookupColumn` and hit `<Ctrl>-<T>`, ensure the `My table has headers` box is checked, then hit `<Enter>`. It will default the table name to `Table1`, change that to `theLookupTable` (or something similar and make the appropriate change in the code above).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to show the first number from your lookup list which is contained in any given order number you can do something like this:

[image: This is it]

It's an array formula so you need to enter it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Assumes there can be only one match per order number and that none of the items in your lookup list are substrings of another item (though a workaround for that would be to sort your lookup list in descending order of item length)

Comment: Ha! I knew there was a way to get an array formula to do this! Much simpler than a regex UDF!